# Is saying "couldn't have" here incorrect?

Tags: modal-verbs, exam-questions

This is the original sentence:

> According to the police, it’s impossible that the prisoner escaped without help from the outside.

This is the transformation that's given as correct:

> The police say that the prisoner can't have escaped without help from the outside.

And this is what I wrote:

> The police say that the prisoner couldn't have escaped without help from the outside.

Can someone tell me why that's incorrect if it is?

Comment: The “formatting" section of our Contributor’s Guide has some good tips for making your question look neat and easy to analyze. You can access it by clicking [here](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners/4799#4799).

Comment: Your version sounds more natural to me. The version with "can't" sounds like perhaps a dialect shade that is not American?

Comment: I have no idea, honestly. This question is part of an exam that is full of all kinds of errors, so I just wanted to ask someone more competent than me.